# Passing a param with a delete button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a button that I want to increment a cart quantity down by 1.

My controller action finds the param (quantity) empty.

How do I make this work please?

I have looked at many SO articles on here to try and find a solution!

```
<% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %> 
        <tr>
            <td><%= button_to 'Remove item from cart', item, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

##### PROBLEM LINE BELOW

            <td><%= button_to ' - 1 ', item, :quantity => 1, method: :delete %></td>
            <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
            <td><%= button_to ' + 1 ', line_items_path(product_id: item.product_id) %></td>


            <td><%= item.product.title %></td>
            <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: The code looks fine, works for me at least.

Comment: It doesnt work for me!  puts params[:quantity]    in the controller delete action prints an empty row in the logs.